# Android 2 separate view animations

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have two separate animations for same progress bar:

```
@Override
public void onProgressStarted() { 

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            mProgressBar.setMax(1000);

            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (mProgressBar, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.5f); // see this max value coming back here, we animale towards that value
            animation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            animation.setDuration (150); //in milliseconds
            animation.start();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(final int progress) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int current = mProgressBar.getProgress();

            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (mProgressBar, "progress", current, progress*10); // see this max value coming back here, we animale towards that value
            animation.setDuration (1000); //in milliseconds
            animation.setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.start();

        }
    });
}
```

How to animate `ProgressBar` progress while simultaneously i have to animate width of the progress line (infinitely/pulse) or `alpha` in this particular case?

Comment: in `onProgressUpdate` what do you need `ObjectAnimator` for? animating "progress" from `current` to `progress*10` (why * 10 ?)

Comment: In my task there is only 0-100%. Rest of it is for eliminating 5fps effect. But it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: So i have no idea what your problem really is,  you need to wait for someone else who has